# Javascript type mismatch error

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and i am unsure why i am getting the error `Type mismatch'

If i simply have the following, it works;

**Working code**

```
newTag = tags.AddNew( 'MyTag0', 'Number0' );
newTag.Update();
```

**Code that returns an error**

```
var p = {
    "MyTag0" : "Number0",
    "MyTag1" : "Number1"
};

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newTag = tags.AddNew("'" + key + "'" + " , " + "'" + p[key] + "'");
        newTag.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that newline between = and { intentional?

Comment: @spassvogel - It's for easy reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are already strings, you do ont have to build up a string to try to look like a string.

```
newTag = tags.AddNew("'" + key + "'" + " , " + "'" + p[key] + "'");
```

What the above code results in is

```
newTag = tags.AddNew( "'MyTag0'", "'Number0'" );
```

It just needs to be

```
newTag = tags.AddNew(key, p[key]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to surround the values with single or double quotation marks

Comment: Then Use ' \" ' escape sequence character for that..@PeanutsMonkey

Comment: @epascarello - Interesting,because when i debug it, it doesn't return as `"'MyTag0'", "'Number0'"` but rather `"MyTag0", "Number0"`. How were you able to get the result ` "'MyTag0'", "'Number0'"`

Comment: @epascarello - Your suggestion worked by the way. Am wondering, why the debug results is displaying something different

Comment: You are doing string concatenation. What would you expect `var a = "A" + "B" + "C"` to be? `"ABC"` Replace A and B with ' and you get `"'B'C"`, replace B with the key and you get `"'MyTag0'"`. You do not need to BUILD a string. `var x = "ABC"; alert(x)` is the same thing as `alert(x);`

Answer (score 0):

Use Something like this :

```
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  var k = "'" + key + "'";
  var pk = "'" + p[key] + "'";
  newTag = tags.AddNew(k, pk);
  newTag.Update();
```

}

Another Idea ( not able to debug but you can try..)

Comment: K,I catch the error,It only pass the array of keys and key,then please change your object p and add commas,and semicolons in it..that you want to add